# Can we have review audits just like SO?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I have a feeling that some user's reviews are not inappropriate.

There are some questions where it's not clear if they should be closed or not, but there are also question that are clearly bad and should be closed. And if a user votes to "Leave Open" all questions, his reviews are not always objective and appropriate.

Comment: Here are the review audits explained in more detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: Please note that reviews are pretty subjective. Not everybody has to share your convictions and opinions.

Comment: @user3470 Please note that there are some [rules](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: But no rules for reviewing. Or are there hidden rules again?

Answer (score 7):

You're setting too much score on review audits. Review audits only prevent users who click blindly to gain badges or ranking, which isn't what's happening here. Besides reviews for close and reopen queues don't work very well, because the automatic selection of audit candidates tends to hit controversial questions.

If you notice that someone is abusing the review system (as opposed to merely having different opinions from yours), you can notify moderators (flag one of their posts). Explain exactly what you saw and why you think it's wrong. Moderators can suspend a user's access to review queues, or fully suspend the user from the site if the situation warrants it.